# Android map with oracle database

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, oracle10g

Hello Every One I want to develop a google map application reading coordinates values from oracle database.Please Provide help me to do this in android using eclips.I have done much googling but i found only solution with SQLlite but i want to do this using oracle database and android

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to do things step by step.

a). First get a simple map application with overlay items working. If you google for Android google maps overlay items you will get a lot of tutorials

b). In the real world scenario it would be most appropriate if your Android app fetches latitudes, longitudes and other details from an Oracle database via a REST Service / JSON API/ Web Service. So you can read up on how to access /  consume a REST Service / JSON API / Web Service. Once you are done with these two tasks it is just a matter of putting things together

Comment: Sir Any Example of your realistic advice so i can test formaly please

Answer (score 0):

> but i want to do this using oracle database and android

You can not have Oracle database on android.

The alternative i see here is -> dump oracle database  on server side and asynchronously read coordinates values from server.

Comment: Sir u r right absolutely i already i have this idea...I only want to ask that how to read data from db via android coding